# a:hover does not change my anchor's list properties

Tags: html, css

Consider my html as follows:

```
<ul id="menu">
<a href="home.html"><li class="highlighted" id="first_item">Home</li></a>
<a href="join.html"><li class="non_selected_tabs">Join</li></a>
<a href="fixtures.html"><li class="non_selected_tabs">Fixtures</li></a>
<a href="club.html"><li class="non_selected_tabs">Our Club</li></a>
<a href="history.html"><li class="non_selected_tabs">History</li></a>
<a href="club_gear.html"><li id="hover" class="non_selected_tabs">Club Gear</li></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

My lists are styled as tabs, and I have my anchors as their parents so that when a user hovers over a tab it becomes selectable

My issue is that I was hoping to use a:hover, or the other anchor properties to change the background colour of my list item...is this possible using CSS?
I can't get it to work so I'm thinking I may have to use some JavsScript?

Comment: whats wrong with "ul#menu a:hover li {background-color: red;}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the `<li>`'s in `<a>` is improper HTML and may not render properly in all browsers. A better solution would be to set the display property of the anchor to `display:inline-block`. Then you will be able to set the width and height of the anchor to the width and height of the li's. This way you can also use the hover property of the anchors.

```
<ul id="menu">
 <li class="highlighted" id="first_item"><a  href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="non_selected_tabs"><a href="join.html">Join</a></li>
<li class="non_selected_tabs"><a href="fixtures.html">Fixtures</a></li>
<li class="non_selected_tabs"><a href="club.html">Our Club</a></li>
<li class="non_selected_tabs"><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
<li id="hover" class="non_selected_tabs"><a href="club_gear.html">Club Gear</a></li>

</ul>

#menu li a
{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
#menu li a:hover
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: There's an extra closing li there... disturbing. You solution works however ;)

Comment: OK, this works, provided I remove the padding within my li. Thanks

Comment: However, how can I know position my text within the anchor? If I use padding or margin's then the background colour doesn't take up the entire space of the li...

Comment: you could wrap the text in spans and style the span

Comment: I tried that, and I can position it horizontally with the span, but not vertically. Any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

The direct children of a `ul` element should only ever be list items elements, not an `a`.

You  could either use `:hover` on the `li` element it's self, this works in browsers that aren't IE, maybe even IE8 and up..

Or you could style the `a` to take up the entire space area of the `li`, and style the `li` to be inline, so not to display as a typical list.

Comment: I already have the li's displaying inline. How do I get the a's to take up the entire space?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :hover on other elements, not just anchors.